# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints when wrapping text

Tags: ios, core-text

I am experiencing 'chicken or the egg' problems with CoreText.

I need to know the `CGSize` an `NSAttributedString` will take up when it is wrapped around an image.
I have a UITableView that displays text and an image in the top right corner.
On my model I store the `CTFrameSetterRef`, i.e. I calculate this once for all
my model entities when they load and then pass my cell a `CTFrameSetterRef` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I also pre-calculate the height of the cell by using my frameSetter and `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints`
This is straight forward, I now have an array of objects that have an AttributedString to render, a frameSetter to render them with and a height so the tableView knows this before updating the cell.

Now I would like to wrap the text around the image in the top right corner.
This presents some problems when I want to pre-calculate the values.

As far as I can figure out I need a CTFrameSetter to calculate a size
(using CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints).
This only gives me the size if my frame is rectangular - If I want to wrap the text I need to create a Path and setting it's size - but this is before I know the size!
Then I need to add the Path to a dictionary and build the CTFrameRef with the dictionary.

**My question is how do I pre-calculate the height for my cell, if my attributed text is wrapped around an Image?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to layout line by line:

1. Layout the first line with the width limit and get line height and `fitRange` using `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints`.
2. Layout the second line below the first one, with the proper width limit — from the heights of preceding lines and the spacing you want you can calculate the origin.y of the current line which you use to figure out whether this line will run against the image, continuing at the end of last `fitRange`.
3. Go on…